# How to predict position with forward Acceleration(with angle) and angularAcceleration?

Tags: forces, acceleration, angular-velocity

I'm working on predicting the path of a point in 2D space for a game;

My point have a direction initial and I want to accelerate on this direction every times, the direction of point is computed with an angle teta like this dir(t) = (cos(teta(t)),sin(teta(t)))

teta(t) = w*t*t*1.0/2.0 + vAzero*t + tetaZero;

teta : Angle of point,
w :Angular Acceleration,
vAzero : velocity angular initial,
tetaZero : angle initial,

With this equation, acceleration equation of my point can be deducted like this :
a(t)= (cos(teta(t),sin(teta(t))*force

a : acceleration,
force : force apply every time

[image]

I have make a simulation with the game engine Unity with this parameter :
[image]

this simulation is make like this

```
for (float t = 0.02f; t < time; t+= 0.02f)
{
    teta = initialAngularAcceleration / 2.0f * t * t + angularVelocity * t + angle;
    timestep = 0.02
    velocity += vec2(Cos(teta), Sin(teta)) * forwardForce * timestep;
    position = position + velocity * timestep;  
}
```

I would get the position at t without know position and velocity at t-1.

My question is the following, How to integrate this equation to get the position movement equation, and too, acceleration equation (a(t)) it is correct here ?

Comment: I don't follow the deduction of acceleration being equal to your direction times force. Acceleration should be equal to the force divided by the mass (more commonly, we say that the force is mass times acceleration, $F=ma$).

Comment: Okay, mass = 1 here and  the acceleraiton aequation will be this : a(t)= F, a(t)= F where F = (cos(teta(t),sin(teta(t))*|F|

Comment: A diagram would help.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're intending there. I was assuming the force was also a vector, but you intend it to be a magnitude.

Comment: So, the force is still a vector but the magnitude of this vector is defined by |F| , exemple, F= (cos(0),sin(0)*2)=(1,0)*2=(2,0)